# Does Equals in c# compare by reference or value?

Tags: c#, .net

```
var A = new obj(1,2,3); //parameters are just used to set some fields no randomness is involved
var B = A;
var C = new obj(1,2,3);
```

i want to make sure if my understanding is correct

- A.Equals(B).Equals(C) (true)
- A == C (false)
- A == B (true)

Does `Equals()` compare the value of all fields and properties between the 2 objects, and is it something that i can trust for sure?

also does `Equals()` use reflection?

Comment: That's depends on how you implement your `obj` class.. Normally, `object.Equals()` method compares by reference.

Comment: Reference types are compared by reference. Value types are compared by value. (There is a reason why reference types are called reference types and value types are called value types!)

Comment: @EricLippert right but i am learning and programming is not what i do for living.

Comment: The `Equals()` and `==operator` can be overloaded. `Object.ReferenceEquals(A,B)` will always tell you if the two objects have reference equality. Object.ReferenceEquals is implemented as `public static bool ReferenceEquals(object objA, object objB) { return objA == objB; }`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on how you write it.

The base `object.Equals()` method compares instances strictly by reference.

You can override `Equals()` in your own classes to do whatever you want.

Finally, `ValueType.Equals()` (inherited by all structs) compares by value using reflection; you should override that when making your own structs.

Comment: so to test for equality in reference types then i have to override, any options to compare reference types by value without writing extra code?

Comment: @user1492051: No, none that I know of. You have to write the Equals function yourself.

Comment: @user1492051: Not only do you need to override `Equals`, but you also need to override `GetHashCode`.  You usually will want to override `==` and `!=` as well.  Further, you need to make sure the equality and hashcode of two objects never changes later (or at least, never changes while the objects are in a hash table).  If you dislike this sort of thing, consider installing a visual studio extension which will generate the code for you automatically.

Answer (score 5):

According to MSDN:

The type of comparison between the current instance and the obj parameter depends on whether the current instance is a reference type or a value type.

- If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object)
  method tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object)
  method is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method.
  Reference equality means that the object variables that are compared
  refer to the same object.
- If the current instance is a value type, the Equals(Object) method
  tests for value equality.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

`object.Equals` (instance) method is resolved at runtime and depends on the type you compare.

If you compare value types it resolves to value comparison, if you use it on reference types it compares references.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`Equals()` needs to be implemented by the writer of the class. When this is not done, a reference comparison is done for reference types and a value comparison for value types. For new value types, it is highly advised to override `Equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):
If the current instance is a reference type, the Equals(Object) method tests for reference equality, and a call to the Equals(Object) method is equivalent to a call to the ReferenceEquals method

Answer (score -1):

You can use Equals in any class that implements `IEquatable<T>,` which has a Equals() method. Under the covers , GetHashCode() is called on the object. So you could have two objects with identical properties but would not be equal since they are different instances with different hash codes.

In order to compare custom classes with Equals you need to implement the `IEquatable<T>` interface and provide your own code in the the Equals method, such as comparing property values.

For example:

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        return this.FirstName == other.FirstName
        && this.LastName == other.LastName;    
     }

     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
        return this.FirstName.GetHashCode() ^ this.LastName.GetHashCode;
     }
}
```

You will want to provide a better hash code method than the example. You can now compare you custom objects using Equals() and comparing property values.